# Subclass Axes in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

The title pretty much says it.
However, the way `matplotlib` is set up, it's not possible to simply inherit from `Axes` and have it work.
The `Axes` object is never used directly, typically it's only returned from calls to `subplot` or other functions.

There's a couple reasons I want to do this.
First, to reduce reproducing plots with similar parameters over and over.
Something like this:

```
class LogTemp(plt.Axes):
    """ Axes to display temperature over time, in logscale """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_xlabel("Time (s)")
        self.set_ylabel("Temperature(C)")
        self.set_yscale('log')
```

It wouldn't be hard to write a custom function for this, although it wouldn't be as flexible.
The bigger reason is that I want to override some of the default behavior.
As a very simple example, consider

```
class Negative(plt.Axes):
     """ Plots negative of arguments """
     def plot(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
         super().plot(x, -y, *args, **kwargs)
```

or

```
class Outliers(plt.Axes):
     """ Highlight outliers in plotted data """
     def plot(self, x, y, **kwargs):
         out = y > 3*y.std()
         super().plot(x, -y, **kwargs)
         super().plot(x[out], y[out], marker='x', linestyle='', **kwargs)
```

Trying to modify more than one aspect of behavior will very quickly become messy if using functions.

However, I haven't found a way to have `matplotlib` easily handle new `Axes` classes.
The docs don't mention it anywhere that I've seen.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470732/how-do-i-subclass-matplotlibs-figure-class) question addresses inheriting from the `Figure` class.
The custom class can then be passed into some `matplotlib` functions.
An unanswered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27473683/can-i-get-the-axis-that-will-be-returned-by-pyplot-subplots-inside-the-constru) suggests the Axes aren't nearly as straightforward.

Update: It's possible to monkey patch `matplotlib.axes.Axes` to override the default behavior, but this can only be done once when the program is first executed. Using multiple custom `Axes` is not possible with this approach.

Comment: The matplotlib documentation has an example of how to create a custom axes: [custom_projection_example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/custom_projection_example.html) There is also a complete [guide on creating scales and transformations](https://matplotlib.org/devel/add_new_projection.html). A usecase can e.g. be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16705452/matplotlib-forcing-pan-zoom-to-constrain-to-x-axes).

Comment: At the end, I think that this is pretty much the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090563/in-python-how-can-i-inherit-and-override-a-method-on-a-class-instance-assignin)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, It's quite similar.  That question is how to modify an already instantiated instance, although your answer covers the situation here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found a good approach explained on [github](https://gist.github.com/btel/a6b97e50e0f26a1a5eaa).
Their goal was an `Axes` object without ticks or markers, which speeds up creation time significantly.
It's possible to register "projections" with `matplotlib`, then use those.

For the example I've given, it can be done by

```
class Outliers(plt.Axes):
    """ Highlight outliers in plotted data """
    name = 'outliers'
    def plot(self, x, y, **kwargs):
         out = abs(y - y.mean()) > 3*y.std()
         super().plot(x, y, **kwargs)
         super().plot(x[out], y[out], marker='x', linestyle='', **kwargs)

import matplotlib.projections as proj
proj.register_projection(Outliers)
```

And it can then be used by

```
ax = f.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='outliers')
```

or

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(20,20, subplot_kw=dict(projection='outliers'))
```

The only changes required are a `name` variable in the class definition, then passing that name in the `projection` argument of subplot.

Comment: Yeah this seems to be the 'offical' way to do this. I started down the road of using internal functions to create new axes and add them to the figure but its way more hassle than it's worth. I think matlotlib are sort of wrong to call this feature "projection", implying it is only useful or used for defining custom projections, when in reality it can be used for customising literally anything to do with axes.